# How not to insert extra line when writing file date to a file

Tags: batch-file

I searched this forum and some kind person provided me with the following code, which enables me to save the date of `myfile.txt` into `date.txt`:

```
forfiles /M myfile.txt /C "cmd /c echo @fdate" >date.txt
```

The problem is, it saves the date on the SECOND line of `date.txt` (inserting a carriage return line feed on the first line). I need the date on the FIRST line.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

filter for lines with numbers:

```
forfiles /M myfile.txt /C "cmd /c echo @fdate" |findstr "[0-9]" >date.txt
```

Comment: wow!..that worked! thank you Stephan! quick followup though. When I use that code I get:

09/05/2015 02:42 PM

Is there a way to just get the date without the time so all I see is:

09/05/2015

?

Comment: OH!! You changed the code and made it work exactly as I wanted!
Bless you!
(So impressed with the speed with which you came up with this..thanks again!)

Answer (score 0):

The empty line is caused by `forfiles`, so you could place redirection in the body:

```
forfiles /M myfile.txt /C "cmd /c > \"date.txt\" echo @fdate"
```

I recommend to state the full path to `date.txt`, especially when you set the switch `/P` of `forfiles` (do not forget to double all `\` in the path as the `\` constitutes an escape character of `forfiles`).

---

If you are satisfied with date/time not including seconds, you could use `for` alternatively:

```
for %I in ("myfile.txt") do (> "date.txt" echo %~tI)
```

Remember to double the `%` signs when you use this command line in a batch file.

Comment: oh my..this works quite nicely as well! Thanks so much.
You guys rock!!

Comment: You're welcome! I added an option with `for` to my answer; please consider to upvote helpful answers, and to accept the answer that helped you most by perfectly solving your problem; that's the way to say "thanks" on SO, and this tells other users which answers are particularly valuable...

Comment: ALL the answers I received were great as all solved my problem. I am very grateful for ALL the suggestions!